# Multiple jQuery UI Dialogs with shellinabox inside one (as an iframe?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to put a console inside of a (nonmodal) jQuery UI dialog on a page with multiple dialogs.

Using an iframe to enclose a shellinabox console almost works:

```
function MakeDialog(title){
    counter++;
    $('<div class="vbox" id=\"' + counter + '\"></div>')
        .dialog({title:title, closeOnEscape: false})
        .dialogExtend({'dblclick':'maximize','maximizable': true, 'minimizable': true});
    return counter;
}

var windowID = MakeDialog('NEURON 7.4 pre-alpha', true);
$('#' + windowID).append('<iframe src="http://localhost:4201" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');
```

The problem is that when I click on a dialog's title bar (raising it to the top), the DOM gets restructured. If, in the process, the iframe is moved, Chrome reloads it, which causes the console state to be lost.

How can I get a console to be one of many dialogs on a webpage?

Comment: In my specific case, the console is the only iframe. A solution that places the corresponding div at the top by moving everything else would work.